# How can I disable a button after four clicks in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a personal menu with a counter, I search to disable a button after four clicks:

```
// Add content button
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = 0;
    $(".counter").click(function (event) {
        $(".count").html(function (i, val) {
            return val * 1 + 1
            x++;
            if (x >= 4) {
              $(this).off(event);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

For easier comprehension, I prefer to use jQuery only if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prop` as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = 0;
    $(".counter").click(function (event) {
        if (++x > 3)
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        console.log(x);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="counter">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with the `off()` function, which is a good method to do it, you have to make a few alterations.

1. The `this` keyword was referring to the `.count` element. That is why the off function was not working. You can change that by using an arrow function instead. Arrow functions don't change the scope of the `this` keyword.

   (An alternative would be to use `event.currentTarget` instead of the `this` keyword.)
2. I also changed the return statement to the last line in the function. Code after the return statement within the same function is never executed.

```js
var x = 0;
$(".counter").on('click', function(event) {
  $(".count").html((i, val) => {
    x++;
    if (x >= 4) {
      $(this).off('click');
    }
    return val * 1 + 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="counter">click</button>
<div class="count">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't need the **jQuery** library for something as straightforward as this.

Here is a vanilla JavaScript approach, instead.

**Working Example:**

```js
let x = 0;
const counter = document.getElementsByClassName('counter')[0];

const clickCounter = () => {
  x++;
  console.log(x);

  if (x > 3) {
    counter.removeEventListener('click', clickCounter, false);
  }
}

counter.addEventListener('click', clickCounter, false);
```

```html
<button type="button" class="counter">Click Me</button>
```